# A curious result from Mathematica on $\int\sin^5x\cos^7x \,dx$

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-integrals

While creating an answer key for my Calc 2 students and trying to save a bit of time, I plugged a trigonometric integral into Mathematica and was a little confused about how it approached the problem. The integral was
$$
\int\sin^5x\cos^7x \,dx
$$

The typical way to evaluate this integral would be to use the Pythagorean identity and a substitution. Something like this:

\begin{align*}
\int\sin^5x\cos^7x \,dx
&= \int (\sin x)\big(\sin^4 x\big)\cos^7x\,dx \\
&= \int(\sin x)\big(1-\cos^2 x\big)^2\cos^7 x\, dx \\
&= -\int \big(1-u^2\big)^2u^7\, du \\
&= -\int u^7-2u^9+u^{11}\,du \\
&= -\frac{u^8}{8}+\frac{u^{10}}{5}-\frac{u^{12}}{12}+C \\
&= -\frac{\cos^8 x}{8}+\frac{\cos^{10}x}{5}-\frac{\cos^{12}x}{12}+C
\end{align*}
Where I've used the substitution $u=\cos x$. We also could have used $u=\sin x$ to get
$$
\int\sin^5x\cos^7x \,dx = \frac{\sin^6 x}{6} -\frac{3\sin^8 x}{8}+\frac{3\sin^{10}}{10}-\frac{\sin^{12} x}{12}+C
$$
which is equivalent up to an added constant.

When I plugged the integral into Mathematica, it spat out
$$
-\frac{5\cos 2x}{1024}
-\frac{5\cos 4x}{8192}
+\frac{5\cos 6x}{6144}
+\frac{\cos 8x}{4096}
-\frac{\cos 10x}{10240}
-\frac{\cos 12x}{24576}
+C
$$

I know this is equivalent to the other two answers. It's a bit tedious to do, but playing around with identities will show this. My question is how could we arrive at this result in a natural way?

From the arguments of $\cos$ being even multiples of $x$ and the powers of 2 showing up in the denominators, it's clear that the power reducing identities are being used. (That is, $\cos^2 x = \frac{1+\cos 2x}2$ and/or $\sin^2 x = \frac {1-\cos 2x}2$.) Typically we would use these if we were evaluating $\int \sin^mx\cos^nx\,dx$, where $m$ and $n$ are both even. But with $m$ and $n$ both odd, I'm perplexed. I haven't been able to find an approach that doesn't require applying these identities *after* integrating.

I've attempted to rewrite the integrand in terms of even powers of $\sin$ and $\cos$, but that was a dead end. I also tried rewriting the integral as
\begin{align*}
\int\sin^5x\cos^7x \,dx
&= \frac 1{32} \int \big(\sin^5 2x\big) \big(\cos^2 x\big)\,dx \\
&= \frac 1{64} \int \big(\sin^5 2x\big) \big(1+\cos 2x\big)\,dx 
\end{align*}
but this didn't quite get me there.

I'd appreciate any help figuring this out, thanks!

Comment: The leading coefficient should be $\frac1{64}$, not $\frac14$

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would guess that it's plugging in $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{ix}}{2i}$, $\cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$, expanding the product, and then rewriting $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x, e^{-ix} = \cos x - i \sin x$ to get it back in terms of cosines and sines.  Or something equivalent.

Comment: @user170231 thanks for the correction!

Comment: @DanielSchepler that would make a lot of sense. I'll try that approach, thanks

Comment: As for why Mathematica gives that result, it follows from applying `TrigReduce` to the integrand. `Integrate` probably has a built-in rule that does this for this specific instance of $\sin^m \times\cos^n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $z=e^{ix}$. $$\begin{align}\sin^5x\cos^7x&=\left(\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}\right)^5\left(\frac{z+\bar z}2\right)^7\\
&=\frac1{2^{12}i}\left(z^5-5z^3+10z-10\bar z+5\bar z^3-\bar z^5\right)\\
&\quad\left(z^7+7z^5+21z^3+35z+35\bar z+21\bar z^3+7\bar z^5+\bar z^7\right)\\
&=\frac1{2^{12}i}\left(z^{12}+2z^{10}-4z^8-10z^6+5z^4+20z^2\right.\\&\quad\left.-20\bar z^2-5\bar z^4+10\bar z^6+4\bar z^8-2\bar z^{10}-\bar z^{12}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2^{11}}\left(\sin(12x)+2\sin(10x)-4\sin(8x)-10\sin(6x)+5\sin(4x)+20\sin(2x)\right),
\end{align}
$$
hence
$$\begin{align}
\int\sin^5x\cos^7x \,dx
&=-\frac{\cos(12x)}{2^{10}\cdot24}-\frac{\cos(10x)}{2^{10}\cdot10}+\frac{\cos(8x)}{2^{10}\cdot4}+5\frac{\cos(6x)}{2^{10}\cdot6}-5\frac{\cos(4x)}{2^{10}\cdot8}-5\frac{\cos(2x)}{2^{10}}+C,
\end{align}
$$
which is Mathematica's result.

Comment: This is the same as Travis's answer, no?

Comment: Yes, we typed simultaneously. @KamalSaleh (It took me 4 minutes more because my answer is more detailed)

Answer (score 4):

Here's another method: The exponential representations of $\sin, \cos$ are
$$\sin x = \frac{1}{2 i} (e^{i x} - e^{-i x}), \qquad \cos x = \frac{1}{2} (e^{i x} + e^{-i x}) .$$ Substituting gives
\begin{align*}
\sin^5 x \cos^7 x
&= \left[\frac{1}{2 i} (e^{i x} - e^{-i x})\right]^5 \left[\frac{1}{2} (e^{i x} + e^{-i x})]\right]^7 \\
&= \frac{1}{2^{12} i} (\color{#ff0000}{e^{12 i x}} \color{#0000ff}{+ 2e^{10 i x}} - \cdots \color{#0000ff}{- 2 e^{-10 i x}} \color{#ff0000}{- e^{12 i x}}) \\
&= \frac{1}{2^{11}} \left[\frac{1}{2 i} (\color{#ff0000}{e^{12 i x} - e^{-12 i x}}) + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2 i} (\color{#0000ff}{e^{10 i x} - e^{-10 i x}}) + \cdots \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2^{11}} (\sin 12 x + 2 \sin 10 x - 4 \sin 8 x - 10 \sin 6 x + 5 \sin 4 x + 20 \sin 2 x) .
\end{align*}

So, integrating gives
\begin{multline*}
\int \sin^5 x \cos^7 x \,dx \\
= \frac{1}{2^{11}} \left(-\frac{1}{12} \cos 12 x - \frac{2}{10} \cos 10 x + \frac{4}{8} \cos 8 x + \frac{10}{6} \cos 6 x - \frac{5}{4} \cos 4 x - \frac{20}{2} \cos 2 x\right) + C ,
\end{multline*}
which agrees with your formula.

Answer (score 3):

As alluded in comments, `TrigReduce` seems to be responsible for simplifying the integrand behind the scenes and producing the $\cos$ sum you see in Mathematica/WolframAlpha. It's anyone's guess as to what exactly `TrigReduce` does to obtain the requisite sum of $\sin$, but here's one possible derivation.

Reduce the powers of all $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms to $1$ with $\cos^2x=\dfrac{1+\cos(2x)}2$:

$$\frac1{512} \sin(2x) (3 - 4\cos(4x) + \cos(8x)) (1+\cos(2x))$$

Now expand and combine $\sin$ and $\cos$ with the identity

$$\sin(2mx)\cos(2nx) = \frac{\sin(2(m-n)x) + \sin(2(m+n)x)}2$$

to get a linear combination of even-argument $\sin$ terms.